# Is Morbius undead?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man

Morbius is a villain from the Spider-Man comics, who essentially gave himself vampirism, but only the kind found in bats. I'm sure I've seen him, however, in the Spider-Man cartoon reacting unfavourably to sunlight, crosses, and holy water.

Which is he? Undead, or human-bat hybrid? And if he is one with traits of the other, is there any in-universe explanation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Michael Morbius, called *Morbius the Living Vampire,* is not a vampire in the classical sense. His vampirism is the result of a serum he created to cure himself of a rare and fatal blood disease. He first appeared in the Amazing Spider-Man #101.**

[image]

- Unfortunately his serum and electrical treatment converted him into a vampire-like being which required blood to survive. His skin became chalk-white and his eyes became blood red and enlarged. He also acquired claws capable of scoring metal.
- He also gained several of the powers of classic vampires including superhuman strength, enhanced regenerative abilities, though not on the order of Wolverine's and the ability to mesmerize weaker-willed humans.
- He possessed a limited form of flight that allowed him to glide on air currents and with the help of a specialized costume had a semblance of flight. This power was considered to be a hyper-developed mental ability accelerated by his transformation.
- While he acquired several abilities that resembled bat-like powers, he did not acquire any of the limitations of the classic undead vampire. He was not affected by crosses, running water or garlic. Nor did his victims become vampires when they are killed by him. He was however extremely photosensitive and avoided direct sunlight when he could help it.